# express return status code for invalid operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I use redux promise middleware for my front end. so action.type will catch if there any error, but what's the correct status code for error I should throw from my backend?

I know I can do `res.status(500).json(something)`

but is 500 correct code for error? like invalid password, should I throw 500 too?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the error code in wiki as well as , they have mention all the error status code you should use.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Most if you have error related to the data in the api , password wrong they come under 4XX error.
Like Password error you should give 401 Unauthorized